# HTML/CSS div line break

Tags: asp.net, html, css

I'm creating a page where the users can post comments, but I have some problems with the `div` which contains the message posted. If it's too long and without line breaks, it appears a horizontal scrollbar. I would like to make the text automatically go in the following line like the comments posted in this site.

Have you got some ideas for making this happen?

I use chrome as browser and asp.net is the server language.

I create the div with:

```
Response.Write("<tr><td><div class=""target-div"">" & reader("commento").Replace(vbCrLf,"br/>") & "</div></td></tr>")
```

Comment: Have you tried setting the white-space value?

Comment: yes, I've tried white-space:pre-wrap; suggested by Andre but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

I think it's

```
.target-div {
    white-space:pre-wrap;
}
```

pre-wrap both saves user formatting (i.e., preserves multiple white-spaces) and wrap when necessary

Comment: it doesn't work :(
This div it's contained in a cell of a table, I don't know if this could be the problem...

Comment: What browser and doctype? Double checked you're setting it to the right element? Can you edit your answer to provide the code or, even better, a fiddle?